# Use Javascript to access a variable passed through Twig

Tags: php, javascript, symfony, twig

I have a controller that passes an array to a twig template, which I want to use in a script written on that page.  How would I go about doing that?

I've tried this in my .twig template:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var test = {{ testArray }};
});
</script>
```

but that only works if it's a string.

Comment: Adding the current output and expected output to your question can make finding a solution to your problem much easier.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You might have to `json_encode` the array, try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var test = {{ testArray|json_encode(constant('JSON_HEX_TAG'))|raw }};
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add quotes
`var test = '{{ testArray|json_encode|raw }}';`

Comment: No, you don't want to quote it. That will make the variable a string containing a json value. Without the quotes it is parsed correctly as an array object.

Comment: You should pass the `JSON_HEX_TAG` flag to `json_encode`: `json_encode(constant('JSON_HEX_TAG'))`.  
Otherwise, you can get broken HTML (try `"<!--<script>"`).

Answer (score 8):

First, send the data json encoded from controller and

then in javascript,

```
var context= JSON.parse('{{ YourArrayFromController|raw}}');
```

Comment: @JoséGabrielGonzález How would you do it ?

Comment: Um, what if some of values in your JSON has single quote? Like in `{"message": "Can't process"}`

Answer (score 5):

**I do it this way:**

Return of the controller test.data then

```
$test = array('data' => array('one','two'))
```

Twig:

```
<div id="test" data-is-test="{{ test.data|json_encode }}"></div>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test = $('#test').data("isTest");
    console.log(test);
});
```

Output:

```
 ["one", "two"]
```

[documentation here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/server-data.html)

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode` works well, in combination with the `raw` filter.

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        let test = {{ testArray | json_encode(constant('JSON_HEX_TAG')) | raw }};
    });
</script>
```

Don't forget the `JSON_HEX_TAG` flag.
Otherwise, you can get broken HTML. [A string containing `<!--<script>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20942452/2534880) is a good way to test that.

Answer (score 0):

In My Controller I Install SerializerBundle

```
$serializer = $this->get('serializer');
        $countries = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("QSCORBundle:CountryMaps")->findAll();
        $jsonCountries = $serializer->serialize($countries, 'json');
 return $this->render('QSCORBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array("countries"=> $jsonCountries));
```

And In My File Twig

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 var obj = {{ countries|json_encode|raw }};
 var myObject = eval('(' + obj + ')');

 console.log(myObject[0]['capital_latitude'] + " " + myObject[0]['capital_longitude']);//for the First Element
</script>
```