# AJAX Calling A Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use Javascript to access a variable passed through Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928729/use-javascript-to-access-a-variable-passed-through-twig)

I have a Twig template and I would like to append the price of the item `{{ item.getPrice() }}` once it has finished loading. I was thinking of doing this in jQuery by using AJAX, but I do not know how to assign a variable to the `url` value and how to assign `{{ item.getPrice() }}` to the variable `offerPrice`.

```
$.ajax ({
  url: {{ item.getPrice() | json_encode | raw }}
}).done( function() {
  $('#price').append(offerPrice);
});
```

Comment: @undefined I actually looked at that thread to get the `|json_encode|raw`. That thread does not address my issue of using how to use an AJAX-like call when I am trying to load a variable and not a URL.

Comment: Okay, note that there is a syntax error in your code, missing `(` for `done` method, also use `console.log({{ item.getPrice() | json_encode | raw }})` for checking what value is returned by calling that code.

Comment: @undefined Thank you, I corrected my mistake. But my issue is that `{{ item.getPrice() }}` is not a URL and returns a price of an item. Therefore, I cannot place it inside the URL parameter.

Comment: Can't you hard-code the URL and concatenate it with that value?

Comment: I don't know where the value `{{item.getPrice()}}` comes from unfortunately. I believe our CMS is retrieving that data from an external service, but I do not have access to that external service.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the final code to look like?