# Accessing javascript variable inside {{ }} symfony twig

Tags: javascript, twig, symfony-2.3

I have an array arr sent from the controller to a twig template containing some JavaScript script , i want to use for loop to access rows of the array like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                alert('{{ arr[i] }}');
            }
```

But the variable i is unknown, i get this error :

> Variable "i" does not exist.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't do that. The javascript variable `i` is only available at runtime.
What you need to do is parse your `twig array` to a javascript one. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928729/use-javascript-to-access-a-variable-passed-through-twig)

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: We don't know what you want to do, add a better example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Javascript to access a variable passed through Twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928729/use-javascript-to-access-a-variable-passed-through-twig)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how to get a php array from the controller to a javascript array through twig:

Controller

```
return $this->render(
    'AppBundle:index.html.twig',
     array(
         'myArray' => array('foo', 'bar', 'z')
     )
);
```

Twig view

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myArray = '{{ myArray | json_encode | raw }}';
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you that's working, just in case somebody needs this, to parse the array myArray you can use :     var jsonData = JSON.parse(myArray);

Answer (score 4):

Twig is PHP. You send its values to javascript but you can't take javascript variables to php. (except AJAX etc... but not relevant here)

Possible:

```
/* javascript variable */
var name = {{ object.name }}
console.log(name);
```

Impossible:

```
/* javascript variable */
var name = 'toto';
{# Twig #}
{{ name }} // <- IMPOSSIBLE
```

Comment: In my case, i'm sending php array to javascript , but i don't know how to parse it.

Comment: You could use the Symfony serializer or if its some simple object:  [Use Javascript to access a variable passed through Twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928729/use-javascript-to-access-a-variable-passed-through-twig)