# php symfony 4 twig slash escaping double quotes is removed and JSON gets broken

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

in my project I am using Symfony 4.3 with Twig and javascript with jquery.

I need to pass a json encoded object from php to javascript, but it gets broken with double quotes. For example, on php side I do the following:

```
$new_obj = new \stdClass;
$new_obj->value = 'Some data with "double " quotes';
print_r(json_encode($new_obj));exit;

return $this->render('mytemplate.html.twig', [
    'new_obj' => $new_obj     
]);
```

So here `print_r(json_encode($new_obj))` gives the following:

```
{"value":"Some data with \"double \" quotes"}
```

and this looks loke valid json because double qoutes get escaped with slashes. But when I get it in my `twig` template, I receive the following:

```
{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Some data with "double " quotes&quot;}
```

So double quotes are replaced with `&quot;` and escaping slash gets removed at all. I can restore encoded quotes back with the following code:

```
function htmlDecode(input){      
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
    return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}
```

but how can I make my json valid again? `JSON.parse()` says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 26
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

[![pic][1]][1]
```

and I have alreadt tried twig internal `{{ data|json_encode() }}` function on my raw object, or `json_encode($new_obj, JSON_HEX_QUOT)` but it did not help.

Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Javascript to access a variable passed through Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928729/use-javascript-to-access-a-variable-passed-through-twig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either turn your variable into a json before passing it to twig :

```
$new_obj = new \stdClass;
$new_obj->value = 'Some data with "double " quotes';

return $this->render('mytemplate.html.twig', [
    'new_obj' => json_encode($new_obj)     
]);
```

And dumping new_obj would show you :

```
{"value":"Some data with \"double \" quotes"}
```

Or you could json_encode it using twig directly inside the page :

```
{{ new_obj|json_encode|raw }}
```

Comment: thats what Im actually doing, but it gives me only `{"value":"Some data with "double " quotes"}`

Comment: Even using the |raw filter ?

Comment: yes, even with `|raw`  filter. weird behaviour: if I see sources of the page, I see my json WITH escaping slashes, but when in console - without them

Comment: Can you show us how you use your twig variable to pass it to JS ? There may be a problem there

Comment: I got it working (`|raw` filter works). Everything we need to do is `var myVar = {{ newObj|raw }}` WITHOUT quotes. I was wrapping already JSON object into it (maybe here my slashes were cut out), and then I was trying to parse it once again. You can add this info into your answer and I will accept it. Thank you

Comment: Your welcolme, that's why I said to directly use `{{ new_obj|json_encode|raw }}`, feel free to validate the answer if it was enough