# Use twig variable for setting chart.js data

Tags: javascript, arrays, twig

i have an issue trying to get the twig values in the html and taking the data for a script that shows a pie chart with chart.js in the html

This is how im adding the current project values from the db in the php controller

```
$TEMPLATE_DATA['PROJECTS'] = $projects;
```

But the field with the data that i need is a json that look like this {"name":"test","size":"348"}

So what i did in the html was doing a for loop for storing in a twig variable the array for that

```
{% set brands = [] %}
{% for project in PROJECTS %}

    {% if project.name %}
    {% set brands = brands|merge([project.name]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for brand in brands %}
   {{ brand |json_encode}}
{% endfor %}
```

this only gets the current names for the projects but ive also need other data from that json, the problem comes when i need to set the data variables for the chart, this is the script

```
<script>

var foo ='{{ brands |json_encode }}';
console.log(foo);

 console.log(typeof(foo));
// console.log(foo);

var data = {
    labels: [
        "Project 1",
        "Project 2",

        "Remaining"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
           
            // data: [30, 40, 13],
            data: foo,

            backgroundColor: [
            "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                // "#FFCE56",
                // "#9861B1",
                // "#007D6F",
                // "#FF5D4D",
                // "#3B4856",
                "#9FADBD"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                // "#FFCE56",
                // "#9861B1",
                // "#007D6F",
                // "#FF5D4D",
                // "#3B4856",
                "#9FADBD"
            ]
        }]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var options = {
  responsive: true,
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom'
        },
  // tooltips: {
  //       callbacks: {
  //           label: function(tooltipItem) {
  //               return "%" + Number(tooltipItem.yLabel) + " usage";
  //           }
  //       }
  //   },
  tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: 'single',
        callbacks: {
            title: function (tooltipItem, data) { 
                return " " + data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index]; 
            },
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']] + " Kb";
        },
            
            // label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
            //     return "Total usage: " + tooltipItems.yLabel + ' €';
            // },
            // footer: function (tooltipItem, data) { return "..."; }
        }
    },
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      formatter: (value, ctx) => {

        let sum = ctx.dataset._meta[0].total;
        let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2) + "%";
        return percentage;


      },
      color: '#fff',
    }
  }
};
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
</script>
```

But at the end i just getting an a  String and not a array of the names, and i cant find a way of using that data to use it in the current chart

Comment: Might help to not quote it if it's not supposed to be a string

Comment: why not build the json object in your php?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Javascript to access a variable passed through Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928729/use-javascript-to-access-a-variable-passed-through-twig)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution to your problem would be to use **| json_encode** pipe in twig, and parse it into JSON with **JSON.parse** to a javascript variable. Here's a brief example:

```
const dataAsJson = JSON.parse({{ brands |json_encode }});
```

Add backticks if needed.

Comment: This is incorrect as `json_encode` does not mark output as safe. Also `JSON.parse` is not required - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/pj82e3)